# Cannot remove ".html" from URL in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, seo

I am trying to remove ".html" from the URL. Attached are my catalog SEO setting in the Magento 2. As you can see I have remove the **".html"** from both **Category URL Suffix** and **Product URL Suffix**.
[image]
I'm stumped as to why it still shows the .html at the end. I have cleared all caches and reindexed all indexes.

Comment: Delete var folder from root and check it after browser cache.

Comment: I deleted everything in the root var folder, cleared all caches and it still shows .html at the end of product URL's even though it's removed from the product suffix.

Comment: We could not even remove the .html suffix as it presented some duplicate entry error.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
UPDATE `url_rewrite` SET `request_path` = REPLACE(`request_path`, ".html", "")
```

It simply removes the `.html` suffix from the URL rewrites table. You then need to reindex after.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,

for me, all pages are working except the home page.

I did all the all settings and reindexed, cache cleared etc, but the error remained.
so finally found the solution for this issue

remove "noroute" from "Default No-route URL" field under Default Page in Stores -> Configuration -> web.

Finally, filed value ll be "cms/index".

this may help one day for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to solve the issue:

- Backup your current Magento2 database
- Delete all records from table `url_rewrite`. You can run the following SQL command:

  ```
  DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE entity_type = 'product';
  ```
- Login to your Magento 2 backend
- Re-save all your Categories
- Clean the Magento2 cache
- Now, you should be able to save/update the `Product URL Suffix` in the `Configuration Settings`.